# Project management tool built into visual studio

Tags: project-management, visual-studio-2010

My friend and I are working on a project together in visual studio, and we are using subversion for source control.  We have used php based project management tools before for task and bug tracking, but we find it inconvenient to go to work in visual studio for hours then have to go find the website and log in and report on what we already made commit notes for, especially since sometimes we are working off line and then have to remember to go back and update the trackers.

We are wondering if there is a project management tool (or set of tools) that is built into (slash an add-on) Visual Studio that will work with AnkhSvn allowing multiple people to maintain and track tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) works very well with Subversion and provides a wiki, ticketing, basic project management, and many community plugins. To achieve the integration between commits in SVN and Trac, you can use Subversion commit hooks to automatically cross-reference commit comments to tickets.

This means that by using AnkhSVN within Visual Studio (or TortoiseSVN outside VS), your commit comments will be copied to an open Trac ticket (in fact I would recommend that this be enforced by using a pre-commit hook) providing the essential link between source control and the ticket system. Using the correct syntax (e.g. "fixes" vs. "refs") you can also close tickets using your commit comments. General ticket/task maintenance still requires you to log in to your Trac website.

Comment: The commit hooks from SVN directly address the question. You use AnkhSVN to commit from VS and the details of the commit comments go into your Trac ticket, achieving the stated goal of not having to duplicate commit notes separately. Using the correct syntax (e.g. "fixes" vs. "refs") allows you to close tickets automatically, although general ticket/task maintenance still requires you to log in to the Trac website.

Comment: This was a really good solution, thanks for your help.

Comment: @RichardM can you work that expansion back into your answer for future reference?